# Docker tag not working for alpine openjdk 11?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, adoptopenjdk

On this page

https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11/

I have the following DockerFile to try out the jdk 11 alpine image like so

```
FROM jre-11.0.6_10-alpine
```

I run Docker and get this error and you can see my login step succeeds..

```
Deans-MacBook-Pro:customerportal dean$ docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /Users/dean/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
Deans-MacBook-Pro:customerportal dean$ docker build . --tag gcr.io/orderly-gcp/customerportal
Sending build context to Docker daemon  103.4MB
Step 1/1 : FROM jre-11.0.6_10-alpine
pull access denied for jre-11.0.6_10-alpine, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
Deans-MacBook-Pro:customerportal dean$
```

How do I try out a jdk 11 alpine image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the full image name

> FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.6_10-alpine

Docker has no way of knowing what image has the tag you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Below two will work

> FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.8_10-debian-slim

> FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest